# LibGdx file (Local) not found on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm having trouble with reading files from Local (as defined by LibGdx), although it works fine to write to it.

What's more troubling is that I can successfully read files in one scenario, but in another not. 
The successful way is when I read a file by using an InputStream gotten from FileHandle.

```
InputStream is = mapFile.read();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "utf-8");
String theString = writer.toString();
hash = new String(Hex.encodeHex(DigestUtils.md5(theString)));
Gdx.app.debug(TAG, hash);
```

What does not work is when I try to load a .tmx map with a TmxLoader as follows:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader(new LocalFileHandleResolver()).load(mapFile.path());

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp.android/files/Downloads/Maps/Smallwoods2 (61)/map.tmx
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.mycompany.myapp.game.maps.GameMap.<init>(GameMap.java:130)
at com.mycompany.myapp.game.maps.GameMapManager.loadMap(GameMapManager.java:56)
at com.mycompany.myapp.game.maps.GameMapManager.access$000(GameMapManager.java:15)
at com.mycompany.myapp.game.maps.GameMapManager$1.run(GameMapManager.java:123)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:452)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp.android/files/Downloads/Maps/Smallwoods2 (61)/map.tmx (Local)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:80)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
```

I even entered into the data directory with adb shell and verified that the file exists.

If I do it with internal files it also works fine.

**edit: I am running this on Android**

Comment: It's a parsing error, according to the stack trace it does find your file, but it fails to deserialize it

Comment: @cedric-martens The SerializationException is being caused by file not being found, so what OP states is correct.
OP how are you running your application? Maybe it has to do with how you set your working direactory.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add that I'm running it on Android. I ran the same code on Desktop, although with internal files and it worked fine. I found some other posts mentioning you have to set the android assets to working directory, but I couldn't find out for sure if that would also mean on Android, and to me it doesn't really seem to be necessary to set working directory on Android. Furthermore, the thing is that it does work to read a file in the same directory in one case, and those files are even written there by the same app, so there must be something else I'm doing wrong... or not.

Comment: You should use the built in functions provided by libgdx to read and write files as they have been created to work on both android and desktop. You can read the text from a file with String text = file.readString() and write to a file with file.writeString()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved my own problem as one often does.

The problem was I was passing an absolute path, but when using a LocalFileResolver you just pass the relative path.

So I was passing

```
/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp.android/files/Downloads/Maps/Smallwoods2 (61)/map.tmx
```

But I should have been passing

```
Downloads/Maps/Smallwoods2 (61)/map.tmx
```